# Server Side HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, server-side

I'm trying to find a C# library that will allow me to "Print" one of my HTML pages to a PDF file.  I can't seem to find out if one currently exists that will allow you to do this.  I've found several that will let you build a page, but haven't noticed if one would generate the pdf only based off of HTML.

EDIT: I'm not allowed a budget on this at work so it will need to be an open source/free product.  If not I'm aware of iTextSharp and will have to generate the pdf programmatically (which is what I'm hoping to avoid :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp comes with a little companion : [XML Worker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/)

For a demo, have a look [here](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/)

Even though the [documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html) refers to the Java API, the adaptation to C# should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a lot of luck with [ActivePDF WebGrabber](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/webgrabber/).  It's kind of odd to use compared to standard managed libraries (ActivePDF is unmanaged), but it gets the job done.

Comment: that looks exactly like I'm wanting, but they seem to like their product a lot and I tend to be an open source fan.  I am rating you up as this library at face value seems to be fantastic, but I've not been given a budget for this at work it's just something that I have to either make a page with existing libraries or find a library that will convert HTML.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely comes with a hefty pricetag.  I used it in at a past job where they had the entire suite at our disposal.  The only open-source component I know of that does PDF rendition is iTextSharp.

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented with [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and it works for basic conversion, but gets complicated when you get into styles and formatting.  I've also heard [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is out there as another option.

Comment: iTextSharp actually lists HTML conversion as a feature that they currently have no plans to support.